# Can't Scale my iOS app to iPhone 5 and 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have been trying to scale my iphone app for a week now. Auto Layout doesn't work and some of my UI elements do not show. How do I get my app to fit all screen sizes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must set the constraint anchors of your subview to trailing and leading of superview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your complete constraints, I can only suggest that you contain all your elements in a vertical stack view. Then pin that vertical stack view at 0px at all sides.